# How can I delete the Jenkins builds by its running duration?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, console, duration

I have a Jenkins job that sometimes runs for more than 1 hour, sometimes it just runs for few seconds. What I really need are those builds with a duration more than 1 hour.

So I would like to delete those builds with the duration less than 1 hour through e.g. the console.

I've tried a lot to find those builds. Unluckily I couldn't find a way to extract the duration information of the builds.

Answer (score 0):

To get the duration of a build through the console :

```
build = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName('JOB_NAME').getBuildByNumber(BUILD_NUMBER)
println build.getDuration() // in milliseconds
println build.getDurationString() // in hour, minutes, seconds
```